# How to work out rampup period in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

I had got stats from log which stated that on avg we have peak load of 3000 logons in 1 hour.

How do I work out the rampup period for jmeter to replicate the same behaviour in 1 hour or 30 mins or 2hr duration

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the ramp-up period, it is more about limiting the rate of requests which are being sent by JMeter to certain rate. So you should be looking at [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) in order to limit JMeter's throughput to the desired rate.

For example,

1. If you want 3000 logins per hour it stands for 50 logins per minute add Constant Throughput Timer as a child of the "Login" request and configure it as follows:

   - Target Throughput: `50.0`
   - Calculate Throughput based on: `all active threads`

     [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]
2. Similarly if you want 3000 logins in 30 minutes - Throughput should be 2x times higher: `100.0` samples per minute
3. And finally if you want 3000 logins in 2 hours - the Throughput should be 2x times lower: `25.0` samples per minute

---

You might also be interested in [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/), it acts similar to the Constant Throughput Timer but it is more precise when it comes to periods lesser than 1 minute and you can also create ["Load Profiles"](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) with it. You can install Throughput Shaping Timer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

Comment: I added a constant throughput timer and set at 50.00, however failed to set 50 per min rather it will ignore the timer and submit the request flooding the server until the server terminates connection.